# Finding a property by name in a class that's contained in array of array

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a somewhat non-trivial containment hierarchy and I'd like to try to use `NSPredicate` to find any element in the list of `scopes` with a property called `name` whose value matches what I provide. When I construct a predicate, I get the error:

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 'name'
```

This is what my class structure looks like:

```
@interface FieldData : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *scopes;

- (Element *)findElementWithName:(NSString *)name;
@end

@implementation FieldData
- (Element *)findElementWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name == %@", name];
    NSArray *result = [self.scopes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
}
@end
```

Scopes is composed either CustomScope or BasicScope class, both of which derive from a common class:

```
@interface Scope : NSObject
@end

@interface BasicScope : Scope
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *scopeElements;
@end

@interface CustomScope : Scope
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *customizations;
@end
```

BasicScope has scopeElements which comprises of:

```
@interface Element : NSObject
@end

@interface ScopeElement : Element
@propery (nonatomic, assign) BOOL enabled;
@propery (nonatomic, assign) NSString *name;
@propery (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger priority;
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of the `scopes` array needs to have the property `name`. Your `Scope` object does not declare a name property.